# Which custom search engine?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-custom-search

I have a website running on `Apache` with `PHP` and `MySQL`.

I wish to implement a custom search engine on text that is stored in the `MySQL` table and on `.pdf` and `.docx` documents.

I am not sure which API to go for.

I have looked at Google's [Custom Search Engine (CSE)](https://cse.google.co.uk/cse/) and [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co). Elastic, I have learnt, can only be run on a Java-based server and so I am unable to go down that route.

I know Elastic can handle my requirements through its REST api. Is Google CSE able to do the same, i.e. search through text stored in Database tables and PDFs? Any other custom search APIs out there that are possible?

Comment: Note that Elasticsearch is also provided as [a hosted service](http://www.slant.co/topics/170/~hosted-elasticsearch-services) and you don't need to install anything.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It's too pricey!

Comment: There are some free hosted plans, though. Browse around the link I shared, and you should find some.

Comment: ElasticSearch runs on Java but it doesn't mean the application needs to be coded in Java. Just need to install ElasticSearch (which is quick) and Java runtime (if not installed). The requests happen over HTTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions such as Google Custom Search Engine (in your case Google Site Search) or even any other web robot (such as [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/)) will only read the web-side of things: what is accessible by a browser (not being logged in) and classify this by URL displaying web-pages (with a title and text content’s extract).

If all PDFs, docx and web-pages are accessible without login, it works extremely well. The web-app creator should enable that. It does not mean that the normal user has access to all, just the robot (e.g. the Springer publisher invites the Google bot to just about all content but not a normal browser).

If you want a search server to access only the fields of your database, it needs to talk to your database. Google Site Search (a form of Google Custom Search) does not allow for that. ElasticSearch and Apache Solr allow that. However, most web hosting services do not make the database ports accessible from outside for security reasons. Thus, you see another requirement for you to run a search server on premises probably.

The requirement to run java or Google CSE seems unavoidable. I know of no solutions of the same quality in other languages (e.g. Drupal can offer a MySQL-based text search but it has a far lower tolerance). Nowadays, many cloud nodes can run java.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious, what type of server does Solr  require? Can it be run on CentOS?

Comment: It requires OpenJDK. Current versions require 1.7 I believe.
Several tutorials indicate how to install Solr on CentOS, e.g. [here](https://blog.nexcess.net/2011/12/30/installing-apache-solr-on-centos/).

Comment: Google's Programmable Search Engine allows querying (or giving weight to) specific fields based on meta tags that you could specify